# How do the "if and (ne)" operators work in helm?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm working with a chart that has the following structure at the beginning but I'm having a hard time understanding when does this evaluate to true.

```
{{- if and .Values.vpceIngress.enabled .Values.http.paths (ne .Values.vpceIngress.class "traefik2") }}
```

I believe that both `enabled` and `paths` must be true, but the `ne` throws me off after that.

Comment: Assuming Helm still uses the Go templating engine, this will return the "first empty argument or the last argument". Arguments are considered true in this templating system if they are not the zero value for their type. Link: https://godoc.org/text/template

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`and` and `ne` are functions in [go templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/).

```
and
    Returns the boolean AND of its arguments by returning the
    first empty argument or the last argument, that is,
    "and x y" behaves as "if x then y else x". All the
    arguments are evaluated.
```

```
ne
    Returns the boolean truth of arg1 != arg2
```

So the template line equates to a more psuedo codish

```
if (
  .Values.vpceIngress.enabled
  && .Values.http.paths
  && .Values.vpceIngress.class != "traefik2"
)
```

The truthiness of the plain `.Value.key` is basically a "is this field/key [not the zero value for the data type](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zero-value-in-golang/). This also works for maps as 'is this field/key defined' due to a map without that path equating to nil or non value (Note that this only works when the parent map is actually defined! Otherwise the template errors)